# Edit all the fasta headers using awk

Tags: fasta, phylogenetics, filtering, data-preprocessing, awk

kindly your comment highly appreciated

have more than 4k header sequences look like:

```
>LTR_retrotransposon100_Gypsy? 
cgtgcaccccaatgttcatagcagcactatttacaatagccaagacatggaaacaaccta aatgtcctttgacaggtgactggataaagaagctgtggtatatttatacaatggaatgct actcagccataaaaaagaataagataatgccatttacagcaacatggatagacctggaga atgttattctaagtgaagtaagccagaaagaaaaagaaaaataccatatgctatcactta

>LTR_retrotransposon10011_ERVK 
taatttgaaaagatacatgcaacccaatgttcatagcagcattatttacaattgccaaga tatggaagcaatctaagtgtccatcaacagatgaatggagagagaagatgtggtatatat acaataaaatactattctgtcataaaaatgaataaaattctgccatttgcaacaacatgg atagacctggagggtattatgctatgtgaaataagtcagacagagaaagacatatactat

>LTR_retrotransposon10011_ERVL-MaLR 
    taatttgaaaagatacatgcaacccaatgttcatagcagcattatttacaattgccaaga tatggaagcaatctaagtgtccatcaacagatgaatggagagagaagatgtggtatatat acaataaaatactattctgtcataaaaatgaataaaattctgccatttgcaacaacatgg atagacctggagggtattatgctatgtgaaataagtcagacagagaaagacatatactat

>LTR_retrotransposon100_Copia 
    cgtgcaccccaatgttcatagcagcactatttacaatagccaagacatggaaacaaccta aatgtcctttgacaggtgactggataaagaagctgtggtatatttatacaatggaatgct actcagccataaaaaagaataagataatgccatttacagcaacatggatagacctggaga atgttattctaagtgaagtaagccagaaagaaaaagaaaaataccatatgctatcactta
```

I would like to use awk or sed to remove everything between the underscore, including the underscore and replace it with / 
plus add sequential RNA followed by #.

and the target output could be:

```
>RNA1#LTR/Gypsy?
ctcagcagcactatttacaatagccaagacatggaaacaacctaaatgtcttatcaatag atgactggataaaggagctgtggtatatctatacaatggaataccatcagccataaaaaa gaataaaatattgccatttgcagcaacatggatggacctggagattatcattctaaggga agtaagccagaaagagaaagaaaaataccatatgatatcacttatatgtggaggtaaaaa aaaaaaaaaagacacaaatcaatttatttgcaaaacatacaTGGActttcagacatagaa

>RNA2#LTR/ERVL-MaLR
taatttgaaaagatacatgcaacccaatgttcatagcagcattatttacaattgccaaga tatggaagcaatctaagtgtccatcaacagatgaatggagagagaagatgtggtatatat acaataaaatactattctgtcataaaaatgaataaaattctgccatttgcaacaacatgg atagacctggagggtattatgctatgtgaaataagtcagacagagaaagacatatactat



>RNA3#LTR/ERVK
    taatttgaaaagatacatgcaacccaatgttcatagcagcattatttacaattgccaaga tatggaagcaatctaagtgtccatcaacagatgaatggagagagaagatgtggtatatat acaataaaatactattctgtcataaaaatgaataaaattctgccatttgcaacaacatgg atagacctggagggtattatgctatgtgaaataagtcagacagagaaagacatatactat

>RNA4#LTR/Copia 
    cgtgcaccccaatgttcatagcagcactatttacaatagccaagacatggaaacaaccta aatgtcctttgacaggtgactggataaagaagctgtggtatatttatacaatggaatgct actcagccataaaaaagaataagataatgccatttacagcaacatggatagacctggaga atgttattctaagtgaagtaagccagaaagaaaaagaaaaataccatatgctatcactta
```

Comment: Is this in fasta format, that is, does the header start with `>`, like so: `>LTR_retrotransposon10011_ERVL-MaLR`? It should not matter for this post, but it may be an important detail for later steps using other bioinformatics tools.

Comment: yes > included, thank you i will edit the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT after OP's update:**

Try this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { $i = 1 } $i += s{>([^_]+)_.*_}{>RNA${i}#${1}/}' input_file > output_file
```

Here, the command line flags are:
`-e`: tells the perl interpreter to look for the code inline, rather than in a file with the script,
`-p`: loop over the input one line at a time, execute the code in the one-liner for each iteration of the loop, and `print` the result into `STDOUT`.
The code has regex replacement (see [`perlre`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for more details):
`s{>([^_]+)_.*_}{>RNA${i}#${1}/}`:
replace an underscore, followed by zero or more occurrences (`*` quantifier) of any character (`.`), followed by an underscore, with slash (`/`).
Keep `>` and the original header part before the underscore, captured by parens into `$1` variable.
Add string `RNA${i}`, where `$i` is the counter of the fasta headers. The counter is incremented by 1 when the substitution occurs, that is, when the next header occurs.
The variables are used like so in the substitution: `${i}`, `${1}` to prevent wrong interpolation.
I am also using `s{}{}` as delimiters for readability (as in most cases) instead of the default `s///`.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
echo ">LTR_retrotransposon100_Gypsy?\nACGT\n>LTR_retrotransposon10011_ERVK\nTCGA" | perl -pe 'BEGIN { $i = 1 } $i += s{>([^_]+)_.*_}{>RNA${i}#${1}/}'
```

Prints:

```
>RNA1#LTR/Gypsy?
ACGT
>RNA2#LTR/ERVK
TCGA
```

Comment: Dear thank you for your response, kindly check the updated question

Answer (score 3):

Your [own answer](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/11389/57) doesn't seem to do what you ask as it doesn't add the sequential identifier to each sequence. Maybe try this?

```
awk -v rec=0 '{
    if($0 ~ "^>"){
        rec++
        sub(">", ">RNA" rec "#", $0)
        sub("_.*_", "/", $0);
    } 
    print $0
}' yourfile.fa
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e 's:^\(.*\)_.*_\(.*\)$:\1/\2:' < input > output
```